# Best practice for using mySQL in Vert.x

Tags: mysql, vert.x

I just discovered vert.x and played a little with it. I love it, however there is one thing that puzzles me: SQL support. Better said, asynchronous SQL support.

I know there is a postgres mod, and even a mysql one but from what I've read on the github page it is still in an early phase.

Also, one should use the event bus to send the query from the requesting verticle to the working verticle that would do the request and then transfer the results back.

However, this doesn't sound like a good idea to me. The communication would be done in text-mode which would imply a lot of serialization/deserialization. Plus, the results would need to read completely and then sent to the requesting verticle which sometimes can be overkill.

And now for my questions:

What is the best way to use mySQL in a vert.x verticle?

Is using the event-bus ok to transfer this much information in text-mode? (or maybe I'm missing something and there is actually a way to send binary data through the event-bus).

Comment: Some time has passed since you asked this question: did you find some answers and would you be willing to share the results?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. I also asked this on vert.x google groups but haven't got an answer. However, I discovered that the event-bus can also support other data types (besides strings).

Comment: Vert.x 3.0 is now in development and possibly with major changes so I postponed using vert.x until that comes out.